# Pull data from Socrata database with $where query from vector

Tags: r, socrata

how can I use a vector to select multiple unique kentekens in RSocrata?

The following function works fine, where the `where` argument allows me to filter on a single kenteken value.

```
kentekens <- RSocrata::read.socrata(
  "https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json?$where=kenteken = '0001ES'")
```

However, I have a vector of (nearly 2000) kentekens of which I want to obtain information from this database. Is it possible to query for this vector, and if so, how?

Comment: It looks like they support an `in` clause: https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/in.html But you still would probably want to break that request up into batched. You're pushing the limits of URL length otherwise.

Comment: `in` would be fine for a few cases, but I have way too many. So RSocrata doesn't support R objects in the query? That's unfortunate. I'll build a for loop for it then.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, RSocrata does not offer a way to support R objects in the query. Howevery, it is rather simple to build a `for` loop and query each kenteken individually.

```
vector_kentekens <- c("0001ES", "0001TJ", "0001WF", "0002GV", "0003ZB")

df_kentekens <- c()

for(kenteken in vector_kentekens ){
  RequestRDW <- RSocrata::read.socrata(
    url = paste(sep = "", "https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json?$select=kenteken,voertuigsoort&$where=kenteken = '", kenteken, "'")
    )
  df_kentekens <- rbind(df_kentekens, RequestRDW)
}
```